# Bedeutung von "zu immer tiefer"

Tags: preposition, meaning-in-context

Kann jemand mir bitte erklären, warum das Wort "zu" im folgenden Satz (aus einem deutschen Buch) nötig ist?

> Dahinter lag ein weiter Talkessel, der - nach innen **zu** immer tiefer
> abfallend - wie ein flacher Krater geformt war.

Ich würde denken, dass dieser Satz ohne "zu" formuliert würde... d. h., einfach "nach innen immer tiefer abfallend." Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nötig ist das „zu“ nicht, aber auch nicht falsch. Es gehört allerdings zum „innen“, nicht zum „immer tiefer“:

> [nach innen zu] [immer tiefer] abfallend

Der Bedeutungsunterschied ist minimal, mit „zu“ betont die Richtung, was in diesem Fall schon impliziert wird.

Deutlicher wird der Unterschied zu Beispiel wenn man einen Ort wählt:

“Nach Köln” hat ein zu erreichendes Ziel und betont die Bewegung, wohingegen
“(Nach) Köln zu” zwar die Richtung, aber nicht notwendigerweise eine tatsächliche Bewegung angibt.

Answer (score 4):

Die im Titel der Frage angenommene Gruppierung ist falsch, es gehören zusammen:

- (nach innen zu) (immer tiefer abfallend)

Die Präposition *zu* ist hier als Richtungsangabe zu verstehen, siehe [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zu#d-1-1-1). *Innen* allein drückt diesen Richtungscharakter nicht korrekt aus, *nach innen* nicht die zunehmende Steigerung im Verlauf, was *immer tiefer* zu kompensieren versucht. Die Angabe *einwärts* würde zwar die fortschreitende Richtungsangabe leisten, aber eine ganz andere Formulierung fordern.

Andererseits ist der Beispielsatz so redundant formuliert (*Talkessel* drückt den  Sachverhalt bereits komplett aus, *flacher Krater* fügt dem schon kaum etwas hinzu, genau so wenig der Einschub in Gedankenstrichen), dass ich den Satz nicht überinterpretieren würde.

Gemeint ist ohne Zweifel, das die Höhe über dem Meeresspiegel abnimmt, je weiter man nach innen kommt.

Comment: Zitat: *»Innen allein drückt diesen Richtungscharakter nicht korrekt aus, ...«* Dem möchte ich widersprechen. Ich entnehme der Version des Satzes ohne *»zu«* exakt dieselbe Information wie der Version mit *»zu«,* und ich empfinde auch stilistisch keinen großen Unterschied zwischen beiden Versionen. Allerdings beobachte ich auch, dass das Wort *»zu«* in einer solchen Konstellation im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums (z.B. bei mir zuhause im Osten Österreichs) viel seltener verwendet wird und noch vor wenigen Jahrzehnten gänzlich unüblich war als das anderswo der Fall zu sein scheint.

Comment: Danke, beide Antworten sind hilfreich!